# Fragments with TabLayout and ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

At the moment I have MainActivity with 2 tabs(with two fragments) and Navigation View with 3  items of menu.
I have only one activity with tabs for now. In MainActivity I have initialization of a Toolbar, NavigationView, ViewPager, TabLayout. Also I have one instance of adapter here, which create fragments for tabs.

When I select one of menu's item, I want it to open a new fragment with two other tabs (with two other fragments).

How can realize it with fragments? 
Or better use additional Activity?

[NavigationView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss6dP.png)

[MainActivity with two tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgEba.png)

**activity_main_xml:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"

            />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight = "6dp"

            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>






<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"

/>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
package ru.alexbykov.sailesstat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.adapter.TheSalesTabsFragmentAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.activity_main;

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager viewPager;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppDefault);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(LAYOUT);


        setupToolBar();
        setupNavigationView();
        setupTabs();


    }

    private void setupToolBar() {


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

    }

    private void setupNavigationView() {

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle togle =
                new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                        this,
                        drawerLayout,
                        toolbar,
                        R.string.view_navigation_open,
                        R.string.view_navigation_close);

//     drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(togle);

        togle.syncState();


        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                switch (item.getItemId())
                {


                }




                return true;
            }
        });


    }

/*    private void startTendersFragment() {


        fTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();;
        TendersFragment tendersFragment = new TendersFragment();

        fTrans
                .add(R.id.frameLayout, tendersFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();


    }*/




    private void setupTabs() {


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        TheSalesTabsFragmentAdapter adapter = new TheSalesTabsFragmentAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }




}
```

**TheSalesTabsFragmentAdapter**

```
   package ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.AbstractTabFragment;
import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.fragmentsTheSale.ManagersFragment;
import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.fragmentsTheSale.PlanFragment;

/**
 * Created by Alexey on 09.06.2016.
 */
public class TheSalesTabsFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {




    //for use strings
    private Context context;
    private Map<Integer, AbstractTabFragment> tabs;



    public TheSalesTabsFragmentAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        this.context = context;
        initTabs();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return tabs.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        return tabs.get(position).getTitle();
    }

    private void initTabs() {

        tabs = new HashMap<>();

            tabs.put(0, PlanFragment.getInstance(context));
            tabs.put(1, ManagersFragment.getInstance(context));

    }
}
```

**ManagersFragment**

```
package ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments;


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;

public class AbstractTabFragment extends Fragment {


    private String title;
    protected Context context;
    protected View view;


    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {

        this.context=context;

    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

**PlanFragment**

```
package ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.fragmentsTheSale;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.R;
import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.AbstractTabFragment;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class PlanFragment extends AbstractTabFragment {

    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.fragment_plan;





    public static PlanFragment getInstance(Context context) {


/*        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);*/


        PlanFragment fragment = new PlanFragment();
        fragment.setContext(context);
        fragment.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.tab_plan_stat_fragment));

        return fragment;


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
        return view;
    }








}
```

**AbstractTabFragment**

```
package ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments;


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;

public class AbstractTabFragment extends Fragment {


    private String title;
    protected Context context;
    protected View view;


    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {

        this.context=context;

    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off fragments are not the best practice ever as are NavigationViews. I would recommend buttons to switch activities with no use of fragments at all. If I understand you right you have your main page with content, in which I would add three buttons, each with an intent to start another activity in leiu of a NavigationView. Each of these activities would have their own buttons which would lead you to whatever activity you want to go to from there.

Comment: I have main page with content (Image 2). This page is created when the application start.  
Why the  use of  fragments and NavigationView is not good practice?

Comment: Yep that ones good that's where you're going to launch other activities from. Fragments are usually only used if you are tailoring the app to both phone and tablet. In a phone they are full screen and on a tablet they show up as a break up of screen space (think settings pages on Apple). Generally they're harder to work with so the general sentiment is that they're pointless to have. NavigationViews are just seen as a lazy programming practice because its easy to stick a bunch of options in there and confuse the user (old Spotify was this and they finally switched)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But In any case I do it for studying. I want to understand how to realize this by using tabs and fragments in one fragment.(selected by user in Navigation Menu)

Comment: Gotcha that's commendable. If you've used intents to change activities its esentially a similar operation, but you're going to use a method called replace. Here's documentation for FragmentTransaction class that includes this:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add new fragment and inside that add viewpager2. May be this will help you.

http://logicrider.com/blogs/viewpager2_with_fragments_and_tablayout_android_studio.php

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33488645)